# Gradebook loop during the cases

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that asks the user if he wants to Average grades or quit, then asks for the students name, then it will allow the user to input grades into 3 different categories, it will loop until he is ready to quit and presses -1.

I created my switch and everything is working pretty good, but how can I loop in Case 1, 2, or 3? Case 1 will be to average homework grades, it will average those homework grades and display them, then itll move to case 2, average those grades and display, which is quiz grades. Then it will move to test grades, user enters grades, presses -1, averages them, then after the third case it will Average all of the student's grades using this formula:

`Final Average = 0.25*HomeworkAvg + 0.25*QuizAvg + 0.50*TestAvg = 64`

How can I add a loop to keep asking for grades, then move on? I feel like I'm sort of on the right track. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner dylan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double homework;
        double quiz;
        double test;
        int choice;
        int choiceTwo;
        String name;

        System.out.println("Enter 1 or 2: \n 1 - Average grades \n 2 - Quit");
        choice = dylan.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter the students name");

            name = dylan.next();

            System.out.println(" What would you like to do? \n 1 - Homework grades \n 2 - Quiz grades \n 3 - Test grades \n -1 - Quit");
            choiceTwo = dylan.nextInt();

            switch (choiceTwo) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter Homework Grades");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                default:
                    if (choiceTwo == -1 || choiceTwo != 1 || choiceTwo != 2 || choiceTwo != 3) ;
                    System.out.println("Exiting program");
                    break;
            }

        } else if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("Exiting program.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid response, exiting program.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You say quit is `-1`, but your code says quit is `2` (initially).

Comment: 2 is for quit in the first menu, but while the user enters grades he can enter -1 to quit entering those grades and move to the next option, for example Homework grades 56  90   84   -1 Move on to Quiz grades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a loop. A `while` loop is great for looping as long as some condition is met. In your case, you should loop as long as `choice` is not `-1`.

It's as easy as changing `(if choice == 1)` to `while (choice != -1`), the removing the `else if` and the `else`; you also should continue to assign what the user inputs to `choice` instead of creating a `choiceTwo`.

You can continue to use nested `while` loops on the same `choice`, too!

```
while ( choice != -1 ) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter Homework Grades");
            // add grades to a list until -1 is typed
            List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while (choice != -1) {
                System.out.println("Enter a grade, or -1 to stop entering grades: ");
                choice = dylan.nextInt();
                if (choice > -1) {
                    grades.add(choice);
                }
            }
            // now calculate your average and do whatever else
            break;
        // more cases
    }
    choice = dylan.nextInt();
}

System.out.println( "Exiting program." );
```

Your code says in the initial menu that you must type `2` to quit, but once the loop begins you must type `-1` to quit. May I suggest you change that? Otherwise, you will have to do something like what Pete suggested, which is less elegant.

Comment: How exactly can I loop it to where when the user enters a grade, it will store that one and ask for them to enter another grade?

Comment: @Darkcobra94 edited to reflect that. I didn't notice you were using a new variable.

Comment: Alright that seemed to help! Also, instead of having them enter all the integers at once, can I make the "Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished" loop? How would I go about doing that? For example:
Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished
56
Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished
76
Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished
84
Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished
-1
Homework Grade average is "homework"

I also want to add that grade to the total int

Comment: @Darkcobra94 nest another `while` loop in there. Let me edit again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some things:

```
boolean complete = false;

while(!complete) {

    //Put your switch stuff here.
    if(choice == -1) complete = true;

}
```